# Orient object on uneven surface

Tags: python, maya

I have an animated locator where it is moving along an uneven surface.
However its axis/ rotational channels are not conforming to the uneven surface.

Is there a tool or script that allows me to make this animated locator to be align/ orient on the surface as it is moving?

Comment: What you're looking for is a ray intersection where you shoot a ray from your object and check if it hits the surface. If it does hit then it'll give you the face it hits, and its normals where you can rotate your object with. Right now this only exists in the Maya api's `MFNMesh` object. You probably need methods `anyIntersection` or `closestIntersection`: http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_class_open_maya_1_1_m_fn_mesh_html

Comment: Now if you're talking about a non-programming approach to this then you're in the wrong forum :), but you can also check out the geometry and normal constraints to make a locator conform to a surface. Both are found in the Constraint menu.

Comment: You might be able with closestPointOnMesh node that output normals from the closest surface. With this you could output matrice or use math nodes to get the rotation. Im not familiar with matrices so Ill test it on monday in maya

Answer (score 1):

First have you tried normal constraint :

```
normalConstraint -weight 1 -aimVector 1 0 0 -upVector 0 1 0 -worldUpType "vector" -worldUpVector 0 1 0;
```

Otherwise, you can use ClosestPointOnMesh (based on uv): https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2008help/Nodes/closestPointOnMesh.html

```
# USER DEFINE
surface = cmds.polySphere(n='pSphere1')
movingObj = cmds.spaceLocator(n='locator1')[0]

# AUTOMATION
aimLocator = cmds.spaceLocator(n='aimloc')[0]
closest = cmds.createNode('closestPointOnMesh')

surface_sh = cmds.listRelatives(surface, ni=True)[0]
cmds.connectAttr(surface_sh+'.worldMesh[0]', closest+'.inMesh')
cmds.connectAttr(surface_sh+'.worldMatrix[0]', closest+'.inputMatrix')
cmds.connectAttr(movingObj+'.t', closest+'.inPosition')

# this command is bugged in python so, lets use mel.eval
cmds.select(surface, aimLocator)
pctr = mel.eval('pointOnPolyConstraint -offset 0 0 0  -weight 1;')[0]

cmds.connectAttr('{}.parameterU'.format(closest), '{}.target[0].targetU'.format(pctr), f=True)
cmds.connectAttr('{}.parameterV'.format(closest), '{}.target[0].targetV'.format(pctr), f=True)

cmds.orientConstraint(aimLocator, movingObj, mo=False, weight=1)
```

You can plug the normal output anyway, I let you follow his tutorial (in russian but every steps are here) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPliNB4uZ0w

Comment: You would have to plug the normal output into vectorProduct utility nodes with cross product to construct your own matrix. This works well too!

Comment: I have to put my head into matrix one day... I think it is the same process that use maya wind. I've always supposed i could direct it with rotation/vector

Comment: I've edited my answer with a really nice tutorial about how to use normal output with matrices :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPliNB4uZ0w